# Variable increases by 1 on high numbers when I don't want to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a weird problem when I'm trying to get a variable from an onClick action. It's supposed to be a Facebook ID, but every time I catch it from the action, it increases by 1. 
JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/aF7sb/

```
<script>
var ajaxSubmit = function(fbid){
  console.log(fbid)
} 
</script>

<i onclick="ajaxSubmit(10152305452512443)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up">Tjo</i>
```

Now this only seem to happen with these high numbers. If you remove the first two numbers, it stays the same.

Any idea how to solve this problem? I'm not even able to reduce it by one, but with two. So weird!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use strings for Facebook ids, not integers: `ajaxSubmit('10152305452512443')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers in JavaScript are all [IEEE754 double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers.

Which means there's about 51 bits for integers.

`10152305452512443` is simply too big for that. If you need to deal with such number, you probably should store it as a string : `ajaxSubmit("10152305452512443")`